# Showing from independence conditions that $P(A) = 1$ or $P(B) = 1$ or $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 0$

Tags: probability, independence

> Show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other and $A\cup B$ and $AB$ are independent of each other, then $P(A) = 1$ or $P(B) = 1$ or $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 0.$

My attempted proof shows that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ can be any values at all, not just $0$ or $1$.

[image]

Comment: My bad, it is AUB and AB

Comment: Well, what is $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)$?

Comment: No, this is an enumeration: the sum of events and their product

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  $A\cup B$ means that at least one of the events $A,B$ happens.  $A\cap B$ means that both of them do.  What event is $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)$?

Comment: AND between events it's not \cap, it's just AND.  The sum and product of these events are considered.

Comment: Do you know what "independent" means?  Do you know what the intersection of two events means?

Comment: In your solution attempt, why are you deriving the first given condition and why aren't you utilising the second given condition? $\quad$ "*The sum and product of these events are considered.*"What does it mean to multiply events? What you are adding in your working are probabilities of events, not events.

Comment: You are right. I apologize for my explanation of the question, translating from my native language to English proved to be a difficult task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have given the condition, that $A\cup B$ and $AB$ are independent. That means, that
$$P((A\cup B)AB) = P(A\cup B)P(AB)$$
but by distributivity we also have $$(A\cup B)(AB) = AB\cup AB = AB$$
Thus we have
$$P(AB) = P(A\cup B)P(AB)$$
From that we can conclude, that either $P(AB) = 0$ or $P(A\cup B) = 1$.
Since $A,B$ are independent, you can show that $P(AB) = 0$ implies that $P(A) = 0$ or $P(B) = 0$, while $P(A\cup B)=1$ implies that $P(A) = 1$ or $P(B) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use your notation: $AB=A\cap B$, the key is to note that: $(A\cup B)\cap(AB)=AB$, then we have

$$P(A\cup B)P(AB)=P((A\cup B)\cap(AB))=P(AB)$$

$$\Rightarrow P(AB)(1-P(A\cup B))=0$$

Case.(1)
$$P(AB)=0\Rightarrow P(A)P(B)=0\Rightarrow P(A)=0 ~~\text{or}~~ P(B)=0$$

Case.(2)

$$\begin{align}1-P(A\cup B)=0&\Rightarrow P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)=1\\
\\
&\Rightarrow P(A)P(B)-P(A)-P(B)+1=0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow (P(A)-1)(P(B)-1)=0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow P(A)=1~~\text{or}~~P(B)=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: You mean "$P(A) = 1$ or $P(B) = 1$" in the end

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.